# can I open excel files in ubuntu using python?

Tags: python-2.7

How do I work on .ods file in ubuntu file using python? Is there any module that can help me interact with excel files using python?

Comment: I think `.ods` files are LibreOffice Calc files whereas Microsoft Excel files are `.xls` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library for handling Excel and .ods files, [pyexcel-ods](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyexcel-ods/0.5.2).

If you only want to read some data, you may also convert your .ods file into a .csv format ('save as ...' in Excel or LibreOffice), which is easy to read.